# Where to find libmyodbc5.so library after mysql-connector-odbc installation?

Tags: linux, mysql, odbc, mariadb

CentOs7

Want to connect my Asterisk installation with MariaDB via `mysql-connector-odbc` driver.

**yum list installed | grep maria**

```
MariaDB-client.x86_64                 10.4.4-1.el7.centos            @mariadb
MariaDB-common.x86_64                 10.4.4-1.el7.centos            @mariadb
MariaDB-compat.x86_64                 10.4.4-1.el7.centos            @mariadb
MariaDB-devel.x86_64                  10.4.4-1.el7.centos            @mariadb
MariaDB-server.x86_64                 10.4.4-1.el7.centos            @mariadb
galera-4.x86_64                       26.4.2-1.rhel7.el7.centos      @mariadb
```

**yum list installed | grep odbc**

```
mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64           8.0.15-1.el7                   @mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-odbc-debuginfo.x86_64 8.0.15-1.el7                   @mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-odbc-setup.x86_64     8.0.15-1.el7                   @mysql-connectors-community
```

I have all packets installed, but no `libmyodbc5.so` exists:

**ls -alh /usr/lib*/libmyodbc*.so**

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.8M Jan 28 07:43 /usr/lib64/libmyodbc8a.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.4M Jan 28 07:43 /usr/lib64/libmyodbc8S.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.8M Jan 28 07:43 /usr/lib64/libmyodbc8w.so
```

`libmyodbc8a.so` is ANSI driver,
`libmyodbc8S.so` is setup lib,
`libmyodbc8w.so` is Unicode driver

But where I can find libmyodbc5.so to use it in Driver64 value?

**cat /etc/odbcinst.ini**

```
[MySQL]
Description=ODBC for MySQL
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage=1

[MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver]
Driver=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc8w.so
SETUP=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc8S.so
UsageCount=1

[MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver]
Driver=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc8a.so
SETUP=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc8S.so
UsageCount=1
```

I thought the `mysql-connector-odbc` packet provides it, but there is no `libmyodbc5.so` after installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this config line: `Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc8w.so`

Anyway, have no idea why default configuration links to unexisting lib.